# Rails 4.0 verifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, verify

in TrackerController of an old app, there is this construct that is alread deprecated in rails 4.

```
verify :method => :post, :only => [ :destroy, :create, :update ],
       :redirect_to => { :action => :calendar }
```

i thought this is how the verification would be translated in routes.rb

```
post 'destroy' => 'tracker#calendar'
post 'create' => 'tracker#calendar'
post 'update' => 'tracker#calendar'
```

but there are no destroy, create or update actions in TrackerController.

next lines have more verifications.

```
verify :session => :loggedin_user_id, :redirect_to => "/login"
verify :session => :selected_user_id, :redirect_to => "/users"
verify :session => :privileged_user,  :only => [:unlock, :destroy_allowance, :acknowledge], :redirect_to => "/Tracker"
```

digging, i thought this would be how above will be re-written.

```
before_action :require_login, require_user

def require_login
  unless session[:loggedin_user_id?]
    redirect_to '/login'
  end
end

def require_user
  unless session[:selected_user_id?]
    redirect_to '/users'
  end
end
```

but then require_user executes also.

how would you re-construct these verifications?

thx!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. Could you clarify it?

That said, if `require_login` is true (no `session[loggedin_user_id?]`), it will short circuit and `require_user` will not run.

As for the routes, well, it depends how you want to do it. The correct way is to make it Restful. For example:

```
resources :calendars # This defines [:index, :show, :new, :create, :edit, :update]
```

If you don't want all of them:

```
resources :calendars, only: [:index, :show, :whatever_you_want]
```

This automatically sets up the following routes:

```
get :index
get :show
get :new
get :edit
post :create
put :update
delete :destroy
```

Which gives you the following helpers which you can use in your links and forms.

```
calendars_path
new_calendar_path
calendar_path(:id) # delete, put, post
```

Comment: my general problem really is how you would reconstruct the verifications to make the system behave the same with rails 4.

Comment: So what is the issue with you current code? What is happening that is causing it to behave differently? Also, what is `require_user` supposed to do?

Comment: i don't know if im asking the right questions. i'm just learning rails and there is this app built ages ago. i'm trying to make it run with rails 4.

Comment: ok.  verify :method => :post, :only => [ :destroy, :create, :update ],
       :redirect_to => { :action => :calendar } is it correct to construct it this way in routes.rb? post 'destroy' => 'tracker#calendar'
post 'create' => 'tracker#calendar'
post 'update' => 'tracker#calendar'

Comment: dont know what require_user supposed to do. i am just guessing based on how i understand the verify :session => :selected_user_id, :redirect_to => "/users"